# Orbeon Forms with Oracle (An error has occurred while processing the request.)

Tags: tomcat, oracle11g, orbeon

I have configured Orbeon 2017.1 PE to work with Oracle 11g, Apache Tomcat-7.0.34. I have deployed in tomcat/webapps. It works out-of-box, but when I try to configure to use Oracle as the database It fails.

- The license.xml is ok
- I have created the Oracle schema and executed the Oracle SQL script. The tables are created, but are empty.
- The charset is AL32UTF8
- I have put the Oracle Drivers in the tomcat /lib
- my context.xml inside context tag:

  ```
  <Context>

      <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
      <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

      <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
      <!--
      <Manager pathname="" />--> 
      <Resource name="jdbc/oracle" auth="Container"
                 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                 initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20"
                 maxWait="30000"
                 validationQuery="select * from dual"
                 driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
                 poolPreparedStatements="true"
                 username="orbeon"
                 password="orbeon"         
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//my.database.server:1521/service"/>

    </Context>
  ```
- I also changed  /webapps/orbeon/WEB-INF/web.xml
  to get the config/properties-prod.xml:

  ```
         <resource-ref>
             <description>DataSource</description>
             <res-ref-name>jdbc/oracle</res-ref-name>
             <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
             <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
         </resource-ref>
  ```

and

```
   <resource-ref>
    <description>DataSource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/oracle</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   </resource-ref>
```

- in /resource/config/properties.prod

  ```
   <properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors">

       <property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="oracle"/>
   </property>
  ```
- Then, when I start Tomcat seems ok:

  ```
  INFO: Deploying web application directory ........./apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/orbeon
  Starting Orbeon Forms 2017.1.201706222319 PE
  Initializing Resource Manager with: {
         "oxf.resources.factory":                                              "org.orbeon.oxf.resources.PriorityResourceManagerFactory",
     "oxf.resources.priority.2":                                        "org.orbeon.oxf.resources.WebAppResourceManagerFactory",
     "oxf.resources.priority.2.oxf.resources.webapp.rootdir":           "/WEB-INF/resources",
     "oxf.resources.priority.6":                                          "org.orbeon.oxf.resources.ClassLoaderResourceManagerFactory"
   }
       Using run mode: prod 
       Using properties file: oxf:/config/properties-prod.xml
      This installation of Orbeon Forms 2017.1.201706222319 PE is licensed to: my name / my org / my email and expires on 2017-11-25
      Property oxf.log4j-config not set. Skipping logging initialization.
      Context listener - Context initialized.
      initializing
      configuring:        FilterSettings(java.util.concurrent.Semaphore@39c75f[Permits = 2],(/fr/.*)|(/xforms-server),(?!/([^/]+)/service/).+\.(gif|css|pdf|json|js|coffee|map|png|jpg|xsd|htc|ico|swf|html|htm|txt))
      d’ag. 30, 2017 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig       deployDirectory
      INFO: Deploying web application directory ..../apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/manager
      d’ag. 30, 2017 9:24:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
      INFO: Deploying web application directory ..../apache-tomcat-7.0.34/webapps/examples
      d’ag. 30, 2017 9:24:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
      INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
      d’ag. 30, 2017 9:24:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
      INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
      d’ag. 30, 2017 9:24:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
      INFO: Server startup in 10512 ms
      Servlet initialized.
  ```
- And when I go to http://localhost:8080/orbeon in the browser only this message appears:

  ```
      An error has occurred while processing the request.
  ```
- And the log:

  ```
      event: {"request": "1", "session": "36072B966078D374692205D2A8529ECB", "source": "limiter", "message": "start: nofilter", "path": "/home/", "method": "GET"}
      not setting credentials headers because credentials are not found
      event: {"request": "1", "session": "36072B966078D374692205D2A8529ECB", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle"}
       /home/ - Received request
       error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/home/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/home/"}

  +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                      |
  |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |URL generator found null URL for config:                                                                                   |
  |<config/>                                                                                                             |
   |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |
  ```

  ... and a lot more log stuff...

**What I'm missing?** Is getting the properties-prod.xml correctly I think.There isn't any database connection error in the log.

**Thank you for your help**.

More info:

When I reference the properties.local or whatever it's named is when the problem starts. If I put in the web.xml a file that not exist as properties.local, it works, but, using the Exist-db mode. Have I to comment some line from web.xml about exist-db?

Comment: This is hard to debug remotely ;). But let's start with a couple of things: 1. In `WEB-INF/resources/config`, can you try renaming your `properties-prod.xml` to `properties-local.xml`? (Don't use `properties-prod.xml` unless you want to have different properties for production and nonproduction.) 2. Instead of using a `context.xml`, put the `<Context>` in Tomcat's `server.xml`, as shown in [this example](https://doc.orbeon.com/installation/tomcat.html#custom-context-within-serverxml). You'll let us know if it helps!

Comment: Done. The same result. :-(
Thank you very much
In the web.xml file there is a propertie that specifies the name of the properties-prod.xml or properties-local. I have changed to local and renamed the file.
I have also changed the resource tag to the server.xml as shown in the example.

Comment: Joan, could you try downloading again a verbatim copy of Orbeon Forms PE 2017.1, uncompressing it, placing the `properties-local.xml` above in `WEB-INF/config`, with *no other changes* to any file, and see what that gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly Oracle isn't the issue. Because the database is still empty, so you would see an error message concerning the persistence layer when you save the first form.
But you see the error already when you start the webpage.
Maybe you have configured UserDatabase for the authentication and the orbeon-auth.war isn't deployed?

Comment: orbeon-auth is deployed, and I haven't configured anything about authentication.

Comment: Have I to comment some line from web.xml about exist-db?  Insert in the properties-local.xml:  <property as="xs:boolean" name="oxf.fr.persistence.exist.active" value="false"/>

Answer (score 0):

I was porting two forms from orbeon CE with postgresql (Orbeon Forms 2016.3.201612302139 CE)  to  orbeon PE with oracle (Orbeon Forms 2017.1.201706222319 PE )

Porting the first form was smoothly; I had to change only the datasource from  postgresql to oracle.
Porting the second  form however had a similar behaviour like yours:
In the browser instead or the form was visualized the error message:
**An error has occurred while processing the request.**
In the log was the following error:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+  
|An Error has Occurred                                            |  
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|  
|assertion failed                                                 |  
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

So the message in the browser is the same as in your experience, the error in the log however is different.

I reduced the form, trying to find the cause.
Surprisingly it was a  xxf:lang()  statement in a compute.
To reproduce the problem I can create a new form and insert in control-1  xxf:lang() as Calculated value or as Initial value.
When I test this form in CE, the form is visualized. In PE instead of the form the message: "An error has occurred while processing the request." is visualized.

So in my case the message "An error has occurred while processing the request." in a first moment also looked like an oracle problem, because I was porting from postgresql to oracle.
But now it is clear that this wasn't an Oracle issue, but depends on the CE and PE software.
NB. I had to install a trial PE, because in CE I can't make tests with oracle.
So my feedback is: when porting forms from CE to PE, there can be forms that in CE start but in PE don't.